# How to assign two models to one marker in ARToolKit

Tags: augmented-reality, artoolkit

I want to make two models appear over one marker in ARToolkit. The key is they much come from two separate  WRL files. Is this possible?

Comment: Hello @jkinz3 do you know how to update kpmHandle with new and existing reference set to avoid long loading time....

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe it is useful for someone else.

The answer is yes, you can.

The way you do it is to have an empty object that is the parent of the other 2 objects and make that object trackable.

The other 2 objects can define an offset in any direction based on the position of the parent, so they will behave as a scene of sorts, keeping their relative positions.